# How can i partition market basket items into clusters?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, partitioning, market-basket-analysis

I have a data set as follows:  (i took a simple example but the real data set is much bigger)

```
     V1 V2 V3 V4
1    1  0  0  1
2    0  1  1  0 
3    0  0  1  0 
4    1  1  1  1
5    0  1  1  0
6    1  0  0  1 
7    0  0  0  1
8    0  1  1  1
9    1  0  1  0 
10   0  1  1  0 
...
```

where V1, V2,V3...Vn are items and 1,2,3,4...1000 are transactions. I want to partition these items into k clusters such that in each cluster i have the items that appear the most frequently together in the same transactions.
To determine the number times each couple of items appear together i tried crosstable, i got the following results:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
V1  4  1  2  3
V2  1  5  5  2
V3  2  5  7  2
V4  3  2  2  5
```

For this small example if i want to create 2 clusters (k=2) such that a cluster must contain 2 items (to maintain the balance between clusters), i will get:

Cluster1={V1,V4}

Cluster2={V2,V3}

because:

1) V1 appears more frequently with V4 (V1,V4)=3 > (V1,V3) > (V1,V2) and same for V4.

2) V2 appears more frequently with V2 (V2,V3)=5 > (V2,V4) > (V2, V1) and same for V3.

How can i do this partition with R and for a bigger set of data ?

Comment: please add the desired result to your question.

Comment: Okey i have just done it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about clustering.  It is not quite the same as what you are doing above, but you could use `hclust` to look for similarity between variables with a suitable distance measure.

For example

```
plot(hclust(dist(t(df),method="binary")))
```

produces the following...

[image]

You should look at `?dist` to see if this distance measure is meaningful in your context, and `?hclust` for other things you can do once you have your dendrogram (such as identifying clusters).

Or you could use your crosstab as a distance matrix (perhaps take the reciprocal of the values, and then `as.dist`).

Comment: Thank you but what matters in my case is the number of times each two products have appeared together and the clusters should be independant.

Comment: @BS.Mira I have updated the dendrogram, which gives the same clusters that you are expecting.  If you have lots of columns, this approach might be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks a lot but how can i fix the desired number of clusters and the number of items per cluster with this method ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes you can just cut the dendrogram (imagine a horizontal line across it) at whatever level you want, to get the number of clusters you think appropriate. See the help for `hclust` and `prune` for pointers on how to do it. It might be harder to fix the number of items per cluster.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
```

data:

```
df<-
fread("
    V1 V2 V3
1    1  0  0
2    0  0  1
3    0  0  1
4    1  1  1
5    0  0  1
6    1  0  0
7    0  0  0
8    0  1  1
9    1  0  1
10   0  1  1
")[,-1]
```

code:

```
setDT(df)
sapply(names(df),function(x){
    df[get(x)==1,lapply(.SD,sum,na.rm=T),.SDcols=names(df)]
    })
```

result:

```
   V2 V3 V4
V2 4  1  2 
V3 1  3  3 
V4 2  3  7
```

Comment: thank you but i think you misunderstood my question. Actually, i have already established that table and based on it i want to cluster items. If for example items V1 and V2 appear together in 5 transactions and items V1 and V3  appear together in only 1 transaction, V2 and V3 in 2 transactions i would put V1 with V2 in the same cluster. So i already have the number of times where they appear together but i don't know how to partition items into clusters based on that.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(text="
ID V1 V2 V3 
1    1  0  0
2    0  0  1
3    0  0  1
4    1  1  1
5    0  0  1
6    1  0  0
7    0  0  0
8    0  1  1
9    1  0  1
10   0  1  1
", header = TRUE) 

k = 3 # number of clusters

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  # group and count on all except the first id column
  group_by_at(2:ncol(df)) %>%
  # get the counts, and collect all the transaction ids
  summarize(n = n(), tran_ids = paste(ID, collapse = ',')) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # grab the top k summarizations
  top_n(k, n)

# V1    V2    V3     n tran_ids
# <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   
# 1     0     0     1     3 2,3,5   
# 2     0     1     1     2 8,10    
# 3     1     0     0     2 1,6
```

Comment: thank you but this isn't the point. If i have for example k=2 and each cluster should contain at most 2 items i would put V2 and V3 together because they have appear together the most (=3). so i would get cluster 1={V1} and cluster 2 ={V2, V3}

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your table and use standard methods of clustering. Thus, you will cluster the items. The features are the transactions.

Geometrical approaches can be used like kmeans. Alternatively, you can use mixture models which provide information criteria (like BIC) for selecting the number of clusters. Here is an R script

```
require(VarSelLCM)

my.data <- as.data.frame(t(df))
# To consider Gaussian mixture
# Alternatively Poisson mixture can be considered by converting each column into integer.
for (j in 1:ncol(my.data)) my.data[,j] <- as.numeric(my.data[,j])

## Clustering by considering all the variables as discriminative
# Number of clusters is between 1 and 6
res.all <- VarSelCluster(my.data, 1:6, vbleSelec = FALSE)

# partition
res.all@partitions@zMAP

# shiny application
VarSelShiny(res.all)


## Clustering with variable selection
# Number of clusters is between 1 and 6
res.selec <- VarSelCluster(my.data, 1:6, vbleSelec = TRUE)

# partition
res.selec@partitions@zMAP

# shiny application
VarSelShiny(res.selec)
```